# Why does std::ios_base::ignore() set the EOF bit?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, iostream

When I read all data from a stream, but make no attempt to read past its end, the stream's EOF is not set. That's how C++ streams work, right? It's the reason this works:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

char buf[255];

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("abcdef");
    ss.read(buf, 6);

    assert(!ss.eof());
    assert(ss.tellg() == 6);
}
```

However, if instead of `read()`ing data I `ignore()` it, EOF is set:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("abcdef");
    ss.ignore(6);

    assert(!ss.eof());        // <-- FAILS
    assert(ss.tellg() == 6);  // <-- FAILS
}
```

This is on GCC 4.8 and GCC trunk (Coliru).

It also has the unfortunate side-effect of making `tellg()` return `-1` (because that's what `tellg()` does), which is annoying for what I'm doing.

Is this standard-mandated? If so, which passage and why? Why would `ignore()` attempt to read more than I told it to?

I can't find any reason for this behaviour on [cppreference's `ignore()` page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). I can probably `.seekg(6, std::ios::cur)` instead, right? But I'd still like to know what's going on.

Comment: Wow, this works on MSVS.  It also failed with clang on coliru.  I think it might be the library and not the compiler itself.

Comment: what happens if you specify a different `delim` besides `eof`?

Comment: @dwcanillas: [No change](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdb33a4a1a87e593).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Looks like [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42857) is the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a libstdc++ bug ([42875](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42857), [h/t](http://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-ht-mean-on-twitter) NathanOliver). The requirements on `ignore()` in [istream.unformatted] are:

> Characters are extracted until any
>   of the following occurs:
>   — `n != numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` (18.3.2) and `n` characters have been extracted so far
>   — end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls `setstate(eofbit)`,
>   which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4));
>   — `traits::eq_int_type(traits::to_int_type(c), delim)` for the next available input character
>   c (in which case c is extracted).
>   *Remarks:* The last condition will never occur if `traits::eq_int_type(delim, traits::eof())`.

So we have two conditions (the last is ignored) - we either read `n` characters, or at some point we hit end-of-file in which case we set the `eofbit`. But, we are able to read `n` characters from the stream in this case (there are in fact 6 characters in your stream), so we will not hit end-of-file on the input sequence.

In libc++, `eof()` is not set and `tellg()` does return 6.

Comment: Glad you agree. :)

Comment: As noted in the report though, the requirements are too vague to clearly label this a bug in libstdc++, it seems more like a defect in the standard. The wording arguably allows an implementation from first checking if EOF is hit, and only checking if `n` characters were already extracted after that. Or checking if `n` characters were already extracted, then checking if EOF is hit, and finally combining the result of both checks.

Comment: @hvd: Arguably.

Comment: @hvd I dunno... certainly violates the principle of expectation here for how operations normally work.

Comment: @Barry Agreed. If it's intended to allow libstdc++'s implementation (which would surprise me), then I would expect the standard to state the requirements in a way that makes it clear it's allowed.